# mongodb elemMatch in dual array

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a problem try to use `$elemMatch` in dual nested array:

Suppose I have this `a` document:

```
a = {'cart': [[{'id': 1, 'count': 1}, {'id': 2, 'count': 3}], [{'id': 1, 'count': 5}]]}
```

And I want to select a document out when `id` is 1 and `count` greater than 2:

```
db.cart.find_one({'cart.0.id': 1, 'cart.0.count': {'$gt': 2}})
```

But this query will select `a` out.

Then I have tried these queries:

```
db.cart.find_one({'cart': {'$elemMatch': {'id': 1, 'count': {'$gt': 2}}}})
db.cart.find_one({'cart': {'$elemMatch': {'id': 2, 'count': {'$gt': 2}}}})
db.cart.find_one({'cart.0': {'$elemMatch': {'id': 1, 'count': {'$gt': 2}}}})
db.cart.find_one({'cart.0': {'$elemMatch': {'id': 2, 'count': {'$gt': 2}}}})
```

But all return None.

So do `$elemMatch` support the nested array match? If so, how shall I tune my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that you have an array within an array, I think you could try something like

```
db.cart.find_one({'cart': {'$elemMatch': { '$elemMatch' : {'id': 1, 'count': {'$gt': 2}}}}})
```

Comment: This works. That said having nested arrays in MongoDB is an issue at this point in time due to the lack of nested positional operators. In other words you cannot always specific elements in the lower level arrays. I suggest a schema change.

Comment: You're right. using $elemmatch in $elemMatch is not a very robust solution; what would one do if he had 10 nested arrays. A redesign of the object's structure is needed